# For which smooth varieties is the Jacobian conjecture known to be true?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, jacobian-conjecture

Let $X$ be a smooth complex algebraic variety. Consider the following properties (RP) and (JC) of $X$:

**(RP) Rolle Property.** Let $f:X\to X$ be a morphism such that the differential $d_x f: T_x X \to T_x X$ is an isomorphism for all (closed) points $x\in X$. Then $f$ is (set theoretically) injective (on closed points).

[Notice](https://www.emis.de/journals/SC/1997/2/pdf/smf_sem-cong_2_55-81.pdf) that (RP) is reminiscent of Rolle's theorem from elementary calculus: if $f(a)=f(b)$ then there's a point $c$ at which $f'(c)=0$.

**(JC) Jacobian Conjecture.** Let $f:X\to X$ be a morphism such that the differential $d_x f: T_x X \to T_x X$ is an isomorphism for all (closed) points $x\in X$. Then $f$ is an isomorphism.

Clearly, in general, property (JC) is stronger than (RP).

In the case of $X=\mathbb{A}^n$ the above properties are equivalent ([thm 1.4](https://www.emis.de/journals/SC/1997/2/pdf/smf_sem-cong_2_55-81.pdf)) and are notoriously an open problem. For some varieties, they're obviously false: $f:\mathbb{C}^*\to \mathbb{C}^*$, $z\mapsto z^2$, has invertible differential at every point but $f$ is not injective (Another example, with $X$ projective, is a nontrivial isogeny of an elliptic curve).

Notice that if $X$ admits a nontrivial étale cover by itself then (RP) and (JC) are false.

> **Q1.** For which varieties are the properties (RP) and/or (JC) above known to be true? (Or, what are some interesting counterexamples?)

> **Q2.** Is there a variety that satisfies (RP) but not (JC)?

Remark: for $X$ projective, whenever $f:X\to X$ is set theoretically bijective, and the differential condition is satisfied, [then](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/164937/conditions-under-which-a-bijective-morphism-of-quasi-projective-varieties-is-an) $f$ is already an isomorphism.

Comment: Do you include Abelian varieties among the "interesting counterexamples"?

Comment: At any rate, the study of smooth projective varieties admitting a non-trivial étale endomorphism is an interesting problem in itself. See for instance https://projecteuclid.org/journals/osaka-journal-of-mathematics/volume-55/issue-2/%C3%89tale-endomorphisms-of-3-folds-I/ojm/1524038727.full for the 3-fold case.

Comment: I wouldn't count Abelian varieties as interesting counterexamples in this context, because they always admit the $x\mapsto -x$ isogeny, so they trivially do not satisfy (RP) or (JC).

Comment: $x \mapsto -x$ is an isomorphism. To have a counterexample, one should take (for instance) $x \mapsto 2x$. Or am I missing something?

Comment: Yes, of course you're right: I meant $x\mapsto 2x$.

Comment: By Zariski's main theorem, an injective morphism of smooth complex varieties is an open embedding. From this it is easy to deduce that an  injective endomorfism of a smooth complex variety is an isomorphism. Hence RP and JC are equivalent.

Comment: I figured ZMT (https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/05K0) implies $f$ is an open embedding. How can one easily see that $f$ is also surjective?

Comment: Well, the image of $f$ must be both open in $X$ (since $f$ is open) and projective (since $f$ is an embedding)...

Comment: I must be missing something. Are you saying $f(X)$ has to be a projective variety? But $X$ isn't nec. projective

Comment: @Qfwfq: sorry, I was thinking only about the projective case

Comment: I believe the Ax-Grothendieck theorem has the following generalization: If $V$ is a variety over an algebraically closed field $K$, and we have a morphism $f : V \to V$ which induces an injection $V(K) \to V(K)$, then $V(K) \to V(K)$ is a bijection. In particular, we cannot have a non-surjective open inclusion from $V$ into itself.

Comment: The model theory wiki states Ax-Grothendieck in this generality https://modeltheory.fandom.com/wiki/Ax-Grothendieck_Theorem , and it seems to me that the standard proof adapts easily, although I couldn't quickly find an official source which says this.

Comment: @Angelo: you weren't thinking of Ax-Grothendieck as the easy step, were you?

Comment: @DavidESpeyer I think that version of the Ax–Grothendieck theorem is [EGAIV$_3$, Proposition 10.4.11]. There are other versions in [EGAIV$_4$, Proposition 17.9.6] and [EGAIV$_4$, (Err$_{\text{IV}}$, 31)].

Comment: @TakumiMurayama Thanks!