# Is a finite injective dominant unramified morphism birational?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $f: X \rightarrow Y$ be a finite injective dominant unramified morphism, where $X$ is a normal and $Y$ is a regular scheme over a field $k$ (which I am not assuming to be algebraically closed or of characteristic 0).

Is it true that $f$ is birational?

Comment: Welcome, new contributor. The answer is no: take $\mathrm{Spec}(\mathbb{C})\to \mathrm{Spec}(\mathbb{R})$.

Comment: For varieties over $\mathbb{C}$, the birationality should be a consequence of the  following result:

If $f:X \to Y$ is a morphism of varieties and either $f$ is finite or $X$ and $Y$ are projective, then $f$ is an isomorphism if and only if $f$ is bijective and $\mathrm{d} f: T_x(X) \to T_{f(x)}(Y)$ is injective for all $x \in X$.

Comment: See https://mathoverflow.net/questions/164937/conditions-under-which-a-bijective-morphism-of-quasi-projective-varieties-is-an